# Illegal mix of collations error in MySql

Tags: mysql, collation, mysql-error-1267

Just got this answer from a previous question and it works a treat!

```
SELECT username, (SUM(rating)/COUNT(*)) as TheAverage, Count(*) as TheCount 
FROM ratings WHERE month='Aug' GROUP BY username HAVING TheCount > 4
ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

But when I stick this extra bit in it gives this error:

> Documentation #1267 - Illegal mix of
>   collations
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for
>   operation '='

```
SELECT username, (SUM(rating)/COUNT(*)) as TheAverage, Count(*) as TheCount FROM 
ratings WHERE month='Aug' 
**AND username IN (SELECT username FROM users WHERE gender =1)**
GROUP BY username HAVING TheCount > 4 ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

The table is:

`id, username, rating, month`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check the collation type of each table, and make sure that they have the same collation.

After that check also the collation type of each table field that you have use in operation.

I had encountered the same error, and that tricks works on me.

Answer (score 106):

Here's how to check which columns are the wrong collation:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, character_set_name, collation_name

FROM information_schema.columns

WHERE collation_name = 'latin1_general_ci'

ORDER BY table_schema, table_name,ordinal_position;
```

And here's the query to fix it:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

[Link](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/bbausili/2010/01/11/mysql-fixing-illegal-mix-collation)

Answer (score 27):

[MySQL]

In these (very rare) cases:

- two tables that really need different collation types
- values not coming from a table, but from an explicit enumeration, for instance:

  SELECT 1 AS numbers UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3

you can compare the values between the different tables by using CAST or CONVERT:

```
CAST('my text' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)

CONVERT('my text' USING utf8)
```

See [CONVERT and CAST documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) on MySQL website.

Comment: They aren't so rare, I am getting them quite frequently on our multilingual site.

Comment: I'm bumping into this problem by making this query using `curtime()`, `SELECT * FROM t_eoms_shift WHERE start_time <= curtime() AND end_time >= curtime();`. This should be an unresolved bug which is addressed [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66480). It works after I decorate the procedure call with `CONVERT()` as `SELECT * FROM t_eoms_shift WHERE start_time <= convert(curtime() USING utf8) AND end_time >= convert(curtime() USING utf8);`

Comment: This is the most useful answer for my situation. I ran into this querying a view with `where view_column_name = 'available'`, adding `CONVERT('available' USING utf8mb4)` fixed it!

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this same error on PhpMyadmin and did the solution indicated here which worked for me

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

[Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error)
Also I would recommend going with General instead of swedish since that one is default and not to use the language unless your application is using Swedish.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should convert to utf8

```
--set utf8 for connection
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
--change CHARACTER SET of DB to utf8
ALTER DATABASE dbName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
--change CHARACTER SET of table to utf8
ALTER TABLE tableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: I used Collate utf8_unicode_ci (as opposed to utf8_general_ci) for issue: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Answer (score 2):

I also got same error, but in my case main problem was in **where** condition the parameter that i'm checking was having some unknown hidden character (**+%A0**)

When ***A0*** convert I got 160 but 160 was out of the range of the character that db knows, that's why database cannot recognize it as character other thing is my table column is varchar

- the solution that I did was I checked there is some characters like that and remove those before run the sql command
- ex:- preg_replace('/\D/', '', $myParameter);

Answer (score 1):

- Check that your users.gender column is an INTEGER.
- Try: `alter table users convert to character set latin1 collate latin1_swedish_ci;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change **each column Collation** from latin1_general_ci to latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error inside a stored procedure, in the where clause. i discovered that the problem ocurred with a local declared variable, previously loaded by the same table/column.

I resolved it casting the data to single char type.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this error is caused by MySQL trying to do an operation on two things which have different collation settings. If you make the settings match, the error will go away. Of course, you need to choose the right setting for your database, depending on what it is going to be used for.

Here's some good advice on choosing between two very common utf8 collations: [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

If you are using phpMyAdmin you can do this systematically by working through the tables mentioned in your error message, and checking the collation type for each column. First you should check which is the overall collation setting for your database - phpMyAdmin can tell you this and change it if necessary. But each column in each table can have its own setting. Normally you will want all these to match.

In a small database this is easy enough to do by hand, and in any case if you read the error message in full it will usually point you to the right place. Don't forget to look at the 'structure' settings for columns with subtables in as well. When you find a collation that does not match you can change it using phpMyAdmin directly, no need to use the query window. Then try your operation again. If the error persists, keep looking!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here mainly, just Cast the field like this cast(field as varchar) or cast(fields as date)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem not because I'm storing in different collations, but because my column type is JSON, which is binary.

Fixed it like this:

```sql
select table.field COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci AS fieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ascii_bin where ever possible, it will match up with almost any collation.
A username seldom accepts special characters anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid changing syntax to solve this problem, try this:

Update your MySQL to version 5.5 or greater.

This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: This may not be true. I have version 5.6.35 and still get this error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with collection warning for a field that is set from 0 to 1. All columns collections was the same. We try to change collections again but nothing fix this issue.

At the end we update the field to `NULL` and after that we update to 1 and this overcomes the collection problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 'utf8' for all parameters in each Function. It's my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was getting Illegal mix of collations while creating a category in Bagisto.  Running these commands (thank you @Quy Le) solved the issue for me:

--set utf8 for connection

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
```

--change CHARACTER SET of DB to utf8

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

--change category tables

```
ALTER TABLE categories CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

ALTER TABLE category_translations CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something strange. I read an api key from a file and then I send it to the server where a SQL query is made. The problem was the **BOM character** that the Windows notepad left, it was causing the error that says:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

I just removed it and everything worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  username, AVG(rating) as TheAverage, COUNT(*) as TheCount
FROM    ratings
        WHERE month='Aug'
        AND username COLLATE latin1_general_ci IN
        (
        SELECT  username
        FROM    users
        WHERE   gender = 1
        )
GROUP BY
        username
HAVING
        TheCount > 4
ORDER BY
        TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC;
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your version of MySQL supports subqueries (4.1+). Next, you could try rewriting your query to something like this:

```
SELECT ratings.username, (SUM(rating)/COUNT(*)) as TheAverage, Count(*) as TheCount FROM ratings, users 
WHERE ratings.month='Aug' and ratings.username = users.username
AND users.gender = 1
GROUP BY ratings.username
HAVING TheCount > 4 ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

Comment: by the way, is your users.gender column an int type?

Comment: I tried that:

SELECT ratings.username, (SUM(ratings.rating)/COUNT(*)) as TheAverage, Count(*) as TheCount FROM ratings, users WHERE ratings.month='Aug' and ratings.username = users.username
AND users.gender = 1 GROUP BY ratings.username HAVING TheCount > 4 ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC

Got the same error as before? 

Yes, Gender is an int.