# SQL join where id equals id and date is greatest

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables,

```
---Jobs---
id,name,.....

---Locations---
id,jobId,Location,date
```

now a job can have more then one location I want to join the job with it's latest location where `jobs.id=location.jobId` and `date` is greatest.

Comment: Do you also have a question for us? (Hopefully something other than just 'do it for me')

Comment: you already know you want to use a sql join. a quick google search provides 20 entries on page 1 on how to do joins exactly as you want.

Comment: It's not crystal clear, but I would guess his/her issue is how to only get the *latest* location, rather than the actual joining?

Comment: I looked in google , did not find anything that helped me The reason I'm asking is because I'm not sure about the syntext.
Shai, Yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jobs J, Locations L
WHERE J.id=L.jobId
AND L.date = (
   SELECT MAX(date) 
   FROM Locations L2
   WHERE L2.jobId=L.jobId
   GROUP BY L2.jobId)
```

Explanation:

In the nested Query I am selecting the maximum date for each Job.

In the external Query i am joining the two tables and fetching only the rows where the date is equal to the MAX(date) i found on the nested query and the Job is the same. This is accomplished by the condition L2.jobId=L.jobId

Comment: I get this error
 #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: Yeah, i probably forgot to use Group By. Query updated. 
BTW that error looks like your tables have different collations. One has utf8_unicode_ci, the other one has utf8_general_ci. Try to make them the same collation. Explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241856/illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: Ya changed to collations and it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from jobs inner join locations on jobs.id=locations.jobid order by date desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Same
I get this error
 #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='