# Complex Two Table Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to a result set that has up to one row per `Sensorrule` row where `Sensorrule.sensorid` exists in `Sensordata.sensorid` with the `DATE(Sensor.messagedate) = CURDATE()` and the `TIME(Sensordata.messagedate) => Sensorrule.fromtime` and `TIME(Sensordata.messagedate) => Sensorrule.totime`.

Resulting set could be less than number of rows in `Sensorrule` if there are no rows in `Sensordata` with the current date (`messagedate`) with the time of `messagedate` between `fromtime` and `totime`.

```
Sensorrule
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------+
| sensorid    | fromtime     | totime     | msg   | name         |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 27460       | 5:00         | 11:00      | Work  | Bob          |
| 27461       | 4:00         | 15:00      | Not   | Susan        |
| 27460       | 7:30         | 12:00      | Max   | Rick         |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------|

Sensordata
+---------+---------------------+---------------+----------+
| Room    | messagedate         | transactionid |  sensorid|
+---------+---------------------+---------------+----------+
| Bedroom | 2014-05-30 07:48:14 | 332243181     | 27460    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-30 05:48:14 | 332243182     | 27464    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-22 07:36:21 | 332243183     | 27460    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-22 09:23:21 | 332656534     | 27464    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-21 06:34:22 | 332243185     | 27461    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-20 06:15:06 | 332243187     | 27460    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-20 07:40:34 | 332243172     | 27465    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-19 09:27:56 | 332243191     | 27461    |
| Bedroom | 2014-05-18 06:34:08 | 332243101     | 27460    |
+---------+---------------------+---------------+----------+
```

Would like the resulting set to look something like:

```
Sensorid    msg     name    
24760       Work    Bob 
27461       Not     Susan
```

Note: Data set above doesn't specifically yield the above result

Comment: Please show the table structure and tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry.  Bad edit when I hit enter.

Comment: What you want in result set I mean what is the select condition?

Comment: If the sensorid from each row in Sensorrule is found in one or more rows of Sensordata table with today's date (messagedate) and the time in messagedate is between Sensorrule's fromtime and totime then output Sensorrule's sensorid, MSG and name. I only want to see one line output (or none) for each row in Sensorrule if that condition exists at least once in Sensordata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct s.sensorid,s.msg,s.name from sensorrule s,sensordata d
where s.sensorid=d.sensorid and 
time(d.messagedate)>s.fromtime and 
time(d.messagedate)<s.totime;
```

Comment: (MYSQL)ERROR 1271 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations for operation '>'

Comment: Was also getting this error message in my previous attempts (thus the ask for help here)

Comment: The problem is with your tables collation types.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241856/illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  Changed s.fromtime and s.totime to explicit datetime format:

e.g. STR_TO_DATE(s.totime,'%H:%i')

That allows the query to work.  However I get many results back (one for each row match in Sensordata rather than just one row for each row in Sensorrule.

Comment: Doesn't that just return one result rather than one possible result for each row in Sensorrule?