# MySQL-query is not working with NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am writing a query that not work correctly

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM admin_marker 
WHERE admin_marker.city NOT IN (SELECT target FROM messsage)
```

It says

> #1267 - Illegal mix of collations
>   (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: Check the collation type of each table, and make sure that they have the same collation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5747047/2899618

Comment: Both column have same collation utf8_general_ci @Uchiha

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to incompatible collations between the two tables. One way to come around it is to use `COLLATE` clause in your query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM admin_marker 
WHERE admin_marker.city NOT IN (SELECT target COLLATE utf8_general_ci 
                                FROM messsage)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf574/1)

Answer (score 3):

This is generally caused by comparing two strings of incompatible collation or by attempting to select data of different collation into a combined column. The clause `COLLATE` allows you to specify the collation used in the query.

Or you can `ALTER TABLE` to match the `COLLATE`

Answer (score 3):

problem is in the collation between two tables , so please try COLLATE for this , may be this is resolve by the Help of COLLATE easily .

```
SELECT * FROM admin_marker WHERE admin_marker.city NOT IN (SELECT target COLLATE utf8_general_ci FROM messsage)
```

and  also check that the data base of that is same

incompatible collation or by attempting to select data of different collation into a combined column. The clause COLLATE allows you to specify the collation used in the query.