# SQL Query Search 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Hi Im stuck trying to search two tables and getting the results I need I have one table with qualifications in with the users id's as well set out like this:

Table name: phpvms_airframe_qual

```
id    pilotid   airframe   icao
0       1001      name     tutr
1       1001      name     eufi
2       1002      name     tutr
3       1002      name     king
4       1001      name     a400
```

Table name: phpvms_aircraft

```
id    fullname   icao    registration
0       tutor    tutr        G-BXEX
1      typhoon   eufi        ZJ932
2       tutor    tutr        G-DXRT
3      kingair   king        ZZ990
4       atlas    a400        ZM400
```

What I need to do is get a list of aircraft but only show ones that the user has the qualification for. So user 1001 will show the following from the example:

```
id    fullname   icao    registration
0       tutor    tutr        G-BXEX
1      typhoon   eufi        ZJ932
2       tutor    tutr        G-DXRT
4       atlas    a400        ZM400
```

and 1002 will show the following:

```
id    fullname   icao    registration
0       tutor    tutr        G-BXEX
2       tutor    tutr        G-DXRT
3      kingair   king        ZZ990
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `phpvms_aircraft` WHERE phpvms_aircraft.icao = (SELECT icao FROM `phpvms_airframe_qual` WHERE pilotid = '1001')
```

But I get errors any Ideas how to do this

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server, which is it?

Comment: `= (SELECT ...)` should be `IN (SELECT ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work but I have not been able to test it.  let me know if it doesn't and what errors come up.

```
SELECT * FROM phpvms_aircraft
    INNER JOIN phpvms_airframe_qual ON phpvms_airframe_qual.icao = phpvms_aircraft.icao
    WHERE phpvms_airframe_qual.pilot_id = 1001;
```

Comment: I have just tried 
SELECT * FROM phpvms_aircraft
    INNER JOIN phpvms_airframe_qual ON phpvms_airframe_qual.icao = phpvms_aircraft.icao
    WHERE phpvms_airframe_qual.pilotid = 1001;

and it comes up with #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @ScottDaniels looks like your tables have different collations.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5747047/2696950 will tell you how to fix it

Comment: Thanks That was the problem got it to work now THANKS ALOT!! :)

Comment: Why accept an answer with a syntax error? I don't get it.

Comment: @Strawberry he must have noticed the error I made and fixed it when he tested the query.  Maybe he just saw my answer and wrote his own query based off my answer, but he left out my error.  In the future, maybe you can make an edit to my answer to fix the mistake.  I fixed it now though, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join to get this answer:

```
 select * from phpvms_aircraft inner p join phpvms_airframe_qual pq on p.icao = pq.icao where ...
```