# Hide Wordpress database error Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' for query

Tags: php, database, wordpress, collation

Does anybody know how to hide just the above error in Wordpress?

Full error below, as too long to put in title:

WordPress database error Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' for query

We can disable all errors easily, but only want to disable this one error, due to the amount of file space that is getting consumed by this one particular error.

Disabling all errors, which we don't really want to do.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to simply not show an error like this without getting into the code.

I suggest you look into fixing the database error by making sure you only use one collation, if possible. Someone that knows mysql should be able to do it in a minute or two.

Here is an example of a case where someone had a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241856/illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal mix of collations error in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241856/illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the input people. Had a look at similar things earlier, but didn't really want to start messing with the database. Have disabled all errors via the wp-config file for the time being, and will have a think on the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.