# special characters in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading data from xml file. my xml file has city name like İstanbul. I check İstanbul in my city table by using select query. but when i echo my sql query in php it show the query in this formate

```
SELECT city_id FROM dc_city 
WHERE (name = 'Ä°stanbul - Avrupa' OR FIND_IN_SET('Ä°stanbul - Avrupa',like_names)) 
AND cultureid = 13
```

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'find_in_set'

Comment: Your collations of your input string and the DB do not match. Try `FIND_IN_SET('Ä°stanbul - Avrupa','a,b,c') collate latin1_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the charset/collation of your table. You have a table which stores its data in ASCII format when you try to filter it with UNICODE (UTF8) strings.

Have a look at [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) to understand the matter.

To change the charset of a table :

```
ALTER TABLE dc_city CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
```

then for your databases

```
ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

MySQL sneaks swedish in there sometimes for no sensible reason.

[Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error?rq=1)