# phpMyAdmin - #1267 - Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I am getting an error when trying to run the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM syshealth WHERE 'timestamp' < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<'
```

I have my table and database collation set to **utf8_unicode_ci**

I have read a few articles already, and have tried the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error), but without success...

Any more idea's?

EDIT: Additional Info - the 'timestamp' column is of type **datetime**

Comment: use backticks to escape column names, not quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ` (backtick) to identify a column if you use single ' , this will be treated as string literal.

```
SELECT * FROM syshealth WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Great! Worked first time.  Does the same rule apply, if I was to execute this within PHP?

Comment: @dankellys, yes same rules with in PHP