# Running a function inside SQL query with selected item as it's parameter

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm doing a MySQL query in an aws-lambda function.

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a js function inside an SQL query where it would use a selected item as it's parameter. like this

```
Left join users user
WHERE ( student.id = user.id AND student.age = '${Process_minimum_Age('user.dateOfBirth')}')
```

or a more realistic example

```
WHERE ( currentLocation = user.location AND currentTime = '${ moment().tz('user.timezone')}' )
```

I'm not sure how to refer back to SQL inside the parameter, when I try it  I get the following error.

```
"errorMessage": "ER_CANT_AGGREGATE_2COLLATIONS: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '='"
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to @H. Figueiredo who kindly and promptly helped me to figure what the problem and gave me the right answer. 
Since I was using template literals and the fact that user.timezone parameter was returning a string I had to wrap it with the following escape quote method ..  `'${moment().tz(``\'us.timezone\'`)
(it's a bit of a challenge escaping backticks here too :)

Comment: Seems to me that you've created the table and fields with a certain collation (utf8mb4_general_ci) and are trying to insert data with a different collation. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: Thank, I know the error says it's a problem with collation but when I remove the parameters inside wrapped single quotes , it won't give me that error but obviously the function wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, so what does the var user.timezone contain? Have you tried to debug it before the query?

Comment: user.timezone returns a string like  'America/Los_Angeles',. When I try to instead use the  moment().tz('result.timeone')}' ouside of the the query and let's say inside the result.map it works fine.

Comment: Just a guess, but could this be your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262648/phpmyadmin-1267-illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation
Not using backticks might make MySQL think you're invoking a var (that doesn't exist)

Comment: Oh! Also in the ${ moment().tz('city') function. The city must be inside quotes! So in your case should be : '${ moment().tz(\"'user.timezone'\")}'

Comment: ok let me try \".."\, BTW, when you said backtick you made me think .. cause I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Hum... Are your template literals wrapping the whole query? That might be the problem, can you try with using them? If you want more help lets move this into chat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189874/discussion-between-h-figueiredo-and-adimona).