# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am working through doctrine and zend framework 2, and while updating the controller class code I got the following error message

> Undefined method 'getFkcountryByName'. The method name must start with
>   either findBy or findOneBy!

```
$country = $entityManager->getRepository('\Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea')->getFkcountryByName($geographical ['nom_departement']);
```

I resolved that by adding the Entity the nom of Repository but I get this Error now:

> An exception occurred while executing 
>   'SELECT c0_.idCountry AS idCountry_0, c0_.codeCountry AS codeCountry_1,
>   c0_.nameCountry AS nameCountry_2 FROM country c0_ WHERE
>   c0_.nameCountry = 'Pyr�n�es-Atlantiques'':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for
>   operation '='

How can I resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error

Comment: Use `COLLATE` in your `WHERE` clause: [Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara ok Thanks in advance

Comment: Please answer or delete your question if you solved it.