# SQL Error: 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_persian_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1064, mybb, mysql-error-1267

MyBB SQL Error

MyBB has experienced an internal SQL error and cannot continue.

SQL Error:

```
1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_persian_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.*
    ,t.subject AS threadsubject
    ,u.username
    ,u.usergroup
    ,u.displaygroup
    ,i.*
    ,i.NAME AS iconname
    ,t.dateline AS threaddate
    ,t.lastpost AS threadlastpost
FROM mybb_threads t
LEFT JOIN mybb_icons i ON (i.iid = t.icon)
LEFT JOIN mybb_users u ON (t.lastposter = u.username)
WHERE t.visible = '1'
    AND t.uid = '54445'
GROUP BY t.tid
ORDER BY threadlastpost DESC LIMIT 5
```

Please contact the MyBB Group for technical support.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5DNR.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQAhB.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error)

Comment: Typically the result of poorly designed tables. Are t.lastposter and u.username defined to have the same collation?

Comment: Please provide more detailed guidance

Comment: Try my solution. maybe it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic/71659466#71659466

Answer (score 0):

Check solution of **Ross Smith II**. He wrote about defining collation in sql statement.

[Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic)

Comment: Please provide more detailed guidance