# fatal error: Illegal mix of collations in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to import a XML-feed to my database. The first 8 records are inserted correctly, but then I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

It's with the following SELECT-query:

```
        $stmt = $this->dbc->prepare(
            "
                SELECT
                            c.category_id       AS category_id
                FROM 
                            categories c
                WHERE
                            c.parent_category_id = :parentCategoryId
                    AND
                            c.name = :name
            "
        );
```

Anyone has an idea to fix this? Via PHP or should I alter the database? I really have no idea, and I already checked the following questions/answers:

- [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)
- [Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, yesterday. What do you mean by _already checked the following questions/answers_?  Have you APPLIED the accepted answer from the second link that you provided?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried but it does not work.