# How layers of character set configuration fit together in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a web app (Rails) which configured to use utf8 for encoding. My database has configuration for character set like:

`show variables like 'char%';`

```
"character_set_client"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_connection"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_database"    "latin1"
"character_set_filesystem"  "binary"
"character_set_results" "utf8mb4"
"character_set_server"  "latin1"
"character_set_system"  "utf8"
```

What I need to do is to convert columns and tables (and maybe the database later) to a different `character set`.

1- In my setup does my app is client in MySQL terminology?

2- When converting a col/table/database, what should I change to not get the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations...
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error

Comment: "When converting ..." -- Show us the command being used.

Comment: I think I have used this: ALTER TABLE [table_name] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charset does not matter with config of the server, a schema/database or the table.There are just the default that cascade from server -> database-> table. The columns and the connection on the other hand have charset and should be consistent to establish a fine database setup.

Comment: And note that "utf8" and "utf8mb4" are different.  (utf8mb4 is better.)